How can I prevent asyncio from choking when I try to finish many tasks?
The following code works fine when I have, e.g, 10 tasks:
    tasks = [asyncio.create_task(do_work(file)) for file in files]
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

Each method call is about 10 seconds of work (mostly waiting on an API to return).
But, when I have ~ 50K files, the tasks take forever to finish. I'm guessing this is because all the tasks are competing for time on the same thread? Not sure.
I tried batching it, like this:
async def main():
    tasks = [asyncio.create_task(do_work(file)) for file in files]
    print("finished creating tasks ...")
    # await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    batch_size = 2
    for i in range(0, len(tasks), batch_size):
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks[i:i+batch_size])

But that didn't help. Which, I guess makes sense, since asyncio starts running the tasks as soon as I call create_task.
What can I do to get maximal performance in processing these files? It's worth noting, that I have a ton of cores. So ideally, each core would have its own asyncio event loop and process work, or something like that.
I've got better performance by doing:
    task_q = asyncio.Queue()
    for file in files:
        await task_q.put(file)

    workers = [asyncio.create_task(worker(task_q, annotate)) for _ in range(500)]
    await task_q.join()
    for worker_task in workers:
        worker_task.cancel()

But, I feel like there's got to be more I can do.

Can you try reducing to 500 worker count to 100 and see if it's faster? Asyncio internally spawns min(32, core_count + 4) threads for IO workload so maybe that's why - tasks competing each others to be allocated in those threads (or I love to call it "IO Jail")
